# Load world from PC to PE

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I see from this question that you can transfer a world from PE version to the PC version. ([How can I import worlds from the PE to the PC version?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194237/how-can-i-import-worlds-from-the-pe-to-the-pc-version))

Is it possible to go from the PC back to the PE? (IOS)

Basically, my son is only using PE version now. If I got the PC version can you keep the two synchronized and if so how hard is it to do?

Comment: It would be near impossible to do it PC -> PE - PC has hundreds of blocks and items that PE doesn't, making this extremely hard. And to synchronize it...... Take that info and multiply it by another near impossible and you get how hard and time-consuming it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, the answer is no. Besides PC and PE are two different versions.