# Is it possible to transfer Minecraft: Bedrock Edition worlds from mobile to PC Java Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

I have a really cool *Minecraft: Bedrock Edition* world on my tablet, and I'd like to have it on *Minecraft: Java Edition* on PC as well. Is there a way to transfer a *Minecraft: Bedrock Edition* world from a mobile device to the PC?

My tablet runs Android, and my PC runs Windows 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I import worlds from Minecraft Bedrock into Minecraft Java?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194237/how-can-i-import-worlds-from-minecraft-bedrock-into-minecraft-java)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using iFunBox, a program for Windows and Mac that allows you to browse your iOS files. You can use it to browse in Minecraft PE and find your world. When you do, you can copy it to your desktop. Hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

Copy `/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds/WorldName` on Android to `%AppData%\.minecraft\saves` on PC

If it doesn't work you need MCEdit (download from [here](http://www.mcedit.net/downloads.html)), import the world on MCEdit and then export it as a PC world

Answer (score 1):

The simplest trick - 100% working:

Copy `/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds/WorldName` from your Android device to `%AppData%\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds` on your PC.

Comment: This works, but only if the storage type is set to "External" in Minecraft settings. If it's set to "Application" it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The world filetype is different I believe, meaning that you can't.

Answer (score -5):

Unless you buy lots of new software, it is practically impossible to do this. (I wouldn't spend my money on it.)