# How do I convert a Java Edition Minecraft world so I can use it in the Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios

I'm trying to convert this .rar file (https://www.planetminecraft.com/project/the-great-gatsby-mansion/) to .mcworld so I can play it on Minecraft PE with my friend. If someone could please help by giving detailed instructions on how to do it, it would be appreciated. :)

I have already tried renaming it to World.mcworld, but when I import it then, it either says World Import Failed, or shows it as a survival world with no name and a seed of 0. (When I open this it is NOT the world.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import worlds from Minecraft PE to the PC version?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194237/how-can-i-import-worlds-from-minecraft-pe-to-the-pc-version)
| NB: Method works both ways

Comment: More accurately, you should be asking: "How do I convert a Java Edition world into Bedrock Edition"?

Answer (score 0):

`.mcworld` files are `.zip` files are indisguise. It'd be natural that Minecraft cannot read `.rar` files.

> How do I convert?

Decompress your `.rar` file using an archiver like [7-zip](https://7-zip.org) or [WinRAR](https://win-rar.com) and then re-compress it as a `.zip` file.

> It still doesn't recognise the world.

See [How can I import worlds from Minecraft PE to the PC version?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194237/how-can-i-import-worlds-from-minecraft-pe-to-the-pc-version)

Bedrock doesn't use the same save formats as Java.

**Note**: Method works both ways.