# Is it possible to transfer worlds from MCPE to MCEE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-education-edition

I have a Bedrock world I want to play with some of my friends, the problem is, most of them use Education Edition (I have no idea why). I tried copying the world folder, converting it to .mcworld, and opening it in MCEE, but it keeps saying ‘level import failed’. Are there any other ways to import MCPE worlds to MCEE?

I am not talking about the *original* MinecraftEDU, I'm talking about the new Education Edition that is based off of Bedrock Edition. So any articles about how to transfer worlds to PC edition aren't for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import worlds from Minecraft PE to the PC version?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194237/how-can-i-import-worlds-from-minecraft-pe-to-the-pc-version)

Comment: @aytimothy  This is to Educational Edition, not PE to PC

Answer (score 1):

To change your minecraft world should be pretty simple. Click on the world and scroll down and click the education edition switch.[image]

A notification will pop up and ask you to confirm. Click yes and you now will have a education edition copy of your world!

Comment: Can players on the *official* Education Edition play cross-edition with Bedrock Edition with EDU features on? If not, you've missed the point of the question.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I am not sure and to tell the truth, I didn't even know the _official_ Education Edition existed until today.

Answer (score 0):

Level Import failed? I know what you did wrong. I have had this issue before. I assume you right clicked the world folder, hit send to compressed folder and renamed it .mcworld. Wrong! What you are supposed to do is: Go into the world folder, and press Ctrl + A. Then right click and click send to compressed folder. You might get an error message that says something like “Failed to copy 1 or more folders because they are empty...” just ignore that and click continue. Then rename that .zip to .mcworld and you have a working world import! Idk if this is compatible with edu edition but level import no longer failed. Double click the file and test it out to make sure it works correctly (It will make a clone of the world).