# How do I convert a world from bedrock to java without MCC ToolChest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I try to convert a Minecraft world from bedrock to java with MCCToolChest, the world comes out as chaos or a void. Also i tried with Amulet but Amulet did not work (I tried converting the chunks but it does not work). I also tried to do it with universal Minecraft editor but it asks me to pay with dollars but I am not in America. Can you please tell me another way or tell me another converter? I am having trouble

Comment: You can pay with the equivalent amount of dollars in your local currency. Ex, if Something costs 10 USD, you can pay 7.46 pound sterling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I import worlds from Minecraft Bedrock into Minecraft Java?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194237/how-can-i-import-worlds-from-minecraft-bedrock-into-minecraft-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a superflat with just Bedrock in Minecraft Java edition go to:

1. more world options
2. select super flat
3. customize
4. press the grass and dirt icon, but leave the bedrock layer alone
5. press "delete layer" that will delete the grass and dirt layer
6. press play on the world

There you go, and if you want buildings spawning press "generate structures".

Comment: Hm I think they’re talking about changing the world not making a custom world

Answer (score 0):

**The officially supported [Chunker](https://chunker.app) tool can be used to convert Bedrock worlds into Java worlds for free, and vice versa. There are also additional options you can change to fine-tune the conversion and world settings.**

Read more about it in the [Minecraft Documention](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/chunkeroverview).

First created as an internal tool, it is now free for anyone to use through a deal with [the Hive](https://hivegames.io/?utm_source=chunker&utm_medium=footer&utm_campaign=public), Microsoft, and Mojang, so it will be supported into the future. It also runs completely through your web-browser, you just need to upload your world file, and then follow the steps.